# Is it possible to set a background-color in CSSGRID?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a problem because I'm not able to set a background-color in my template. I tried to put it in container, but size of image wasn't fitting with others. Is it any solution for this? It's important that 4th element was also on center like other elements, but I want it's background to set as red :)

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
         box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        ol, ul {
            list-style: none; }
          
        
        
        body{
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        }
        nav {
        
             flex-basis: 10vh;
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr 2fr;
             background-color: red;
        }

         .settings {
             grid-column: 1/ span 1;
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
             padding-left: 2vw;
             margin-right: 2vw;
             background-color: blue;
        }
         .settings__logo {
             align-self: center;
        }
         .settings__photo {
             width: 50%;
        }
         .navigation {
             grid-column: 2/ span 1;
             display: grid;
             grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
             padding-left: 2vw;
             margin-right: 2vw;
        }
         .navigation__logo {
             align-self: center;
        }
         .navigation__photo {
             width: 60%;
        }
.diffrent{
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
            <ul class="settings">
                <li class="settings__logo" data-list-type="models"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        class="settings__photo"></li>
                <li class="settings__logo" data-list-type="colors"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        class="settings__photo"></li>
                <li class="settings__logo" data-list-type="company"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        class="settings__photo"></li>
                  <li class="settings__logo diffrent" data-list-type="company"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
                        class="settings__photo"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li class="navigation__logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="navigation__photo"></li>
                <li class="navigation__logo"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="navigation__photo"></li>
                <li class="navigation__logo"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="navigation__photo"></li>
                <li class="navigation__logo"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="navigation__photo"></li>
                <li class="navigation__logo"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="navigation__photo"></li>
            </ul>
    
        </nav>
```

Comment: don't align the li element, keep it stretch by default and align the content inside